# Наличие дочернего элемента

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!

Есть несколько пунктов меню *.js-dropDown*
Если у него нету в дочернем элементе *.js-dropDown-box* то дочерней ссылке .*js-dropDown-toggle* нужно дать класс *.no-drop*

Ниже пример HTML разметки

```
<li class="hasChild js-dropDown">
    <a href="/catalog/dom/" class="js-dropDown-toggle" title="Дом" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Дом</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="js-dropDown-box">
        <li><a href="/catalog/vip_suveniry/">VIP сувениры</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="hasChild js-dropDown">
    <a href="/catalog/domq/" class="js-dropDown-toggle" title="Дом" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Дом</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Попытался реализовать таким методом, но не получается.

```
$( ".hasChild.js-dropDown" ).each(function() {
     if($(this).children('.js-dropDown-box').leght > 0) {
    var link = $(this).children('.js-dropDown-toggle');
    link.addClass('no-drop');
     }

});
```

Что я делаю не так? 
Спасибо!

Comment: `leght ` ?.....

Comment: Да,  он) 
Невнимательность(
Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не исправляйте очепятку, иначе при чтении вопроса новыми участниками возникнет путаница. Можно дописать ниже где ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Если у него **нету** в дочернем элементе .js-dropDown-box ...

и дальше условие

> if($(this).children('.js-dropDown-box').leght > 0) {

тут проверяется что наследники **присутствуют**

вот код с правками:

```
$( ".hasChild.js-dropDown" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).children('.js-dropDown-box').length  == 0) {
    var link = $(this).children('.js-dropDown-toggle');
    link.addClass('no-drop');
     }

});
```

Comment: leght -> length

Comment: и, да, конечно   leght -> length

Comment: Это должно быть в ответе :)

Comment: еще можно проверить `has()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".hasChild.js-dropDown" ).each(function() {
     if(!$(this).children('.js-dropDown-box').length > 0) {
    var link = $(this).children('.js-dropDown-toggle');
    link.addClass('no-drop');
     }

});
```

проблему решил
*length*
*!$(this)*

Переписал

```
'use strict';
// hide navbar icon
    document.querySelectorAll('.js-dropDown').forEach( dropdown => {
     const haschild = !!dropdown.querySelector('.js-dropDown-box');
      if(!haschild) dropdown.querySelector('.js-dropDown-toggle').classList.add('no-drop');
    })
```